# How does htaccess recursion work?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

I'm working in a hosted situation where I have a primary webroot located in `~/www`. I have several subdomains hosted in `~/www/__subdomains`. In the primary webroot, I have a `.htaccess` file that does a bit of minor rewriting. In two of my subdomains, I have similar `.htaccess` files and these subdomains respond properly.

In 2 other, newly created subdomains, I have `.htaccess` files that are empty save for an `AddHandler` directive. What I'm finding is that the root `.htaccess` file's existence/content affects these 2 subdomains. They throw a 500 error. As soon as I rename that one, the broken subdomains work.

This, of course, breaks the other sites so I can't just move this off, but it violates my understanding of how `.htaccess` recursion works. I thought that as long as there was a `.htaccess` file in a subdirectory, those in ancestor directories would never get executed.

Clearly, I'm wrong about that so I'm hoping someone can educate me and help me get this fixed.

Thanks.

Comment: "I thought that as long as there was a .htaccess file in a subdirectory, those in ancestor directories would never get executed.".  Nope, it walks up the whole directory tree for every request.  This is one of the disadvantages of htaccess: this traversal adds nontrivial overhead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.htaccess` files are applied from the current directory up, stopping at the main configuration.  Any rules and directives that are in the current directory's `.htaccess` file, supersede any other rules found while evaluating `.htaccess` further up.

However, the problem, as you've found, is that rules that aren't explicitly overridden, are applied from the other files.  You can reference the [Apache .htaccess Tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) for further explanation, specifically, the **How directives are applied** section.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That does help. I guess I didn't realize that the rules cascaded. I thought it was more of a stop when you find the first `.htaccess` kind of thing. I ended up by turning the `RewriteEngine` off for the appropriate subdomains, but this helps me understand why. Thanks.

Comment: I personally find this very intuitive.

Comment: `.htaccess files are applied from the current directory up, stopping at the main configuration`. I'm sure this wasn't the original intent, but this sentence seems to imply that a file `/foo/bar/.htaccess` will apply "upwards" to  a request for a file at `/foo/my.php`, which I don't think is the case.